# How to disable LFS check in GitHub (Desktop)?

Tags: github, git-lfs

I have to disable lfs check in GitHub as it's not pushing some of my files and saying that they are corrupt and all. I read that I could disable it by this command: 'git config lfs.allowincompletepush true', but where do I write it or execute it?

I tried in the .gitattributes file but don't know how to do that, it didn't work. Please guide me!

Comment: Could you try running git lfs fetch --all and then git lfs checkout? It tends to happen, that it tells you, that files are corrupted while they are actually missing.

Comment: I don't get it. Please tell me where do I write these commands and execute them? I don't know anything about it how to do. And please write the commands in double quotes so I could understand.

Comment: You run those command wherever your .git folder is in your project (parent folder  of .git). "git lfs fetch --all" fetches all possibly missing files. "git lfs checkout" updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or the specified tree. (I'd first run only fetch, try if it helped and then checkout). Also I'd recommend doing a local backup of your progress before you start fetching into your project.

Comment: I am using github desktop and in that, if you know, I just have a local folder which I connect to the software (that only contains the .gitattributes notepad file). Where to write in that? What to do? I still don't understand where do I have to write these commands. In Command Prompt or some other git software?

Comment: .git folder is a hidden folder, that is supposed to be in the root of you project. So in open a command prompt in the root of your project and try those commands in the way I explained before

Comment: I did that but in the command prompt, when I write the command - "git lfs fetch" in that folder, it says - "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." :\
And do i need to install Git software from github as shown in this video? : https://youtu.be/xPFLAAhuGy0